# What is the correct DTD for Schema DATA placement in XHTML pages?

Tags: microdata, xhtml, w3c-validation

We get W3C validation error after placing Scheme Data in our website which was built in XHTML.

> Line 198, Column 41: there is no attribute "`data-id`"
>
> ```
> <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="322498" data-counter="right"></script>
> ```

([Link to the validator result](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.macronimous.com%2Faboutus.asp&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices))

Will changing the DTD solve this? We use,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Or just use `<!DOCTYPE html>` and skip the nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-*` attributes are [defined for (X)HTML5 only](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140429/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

The [Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/) attributes (`itemscope`, `itemprop`, …) are defined for (X)HTML5 only.

So when you switch to (X)HTML5, you can use both of these.

If you want to keep using XHTML 1.0, you could use `class` instead of `data-*` attributes, and RDFa instead of Microdata (which requires [adjusting your DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974898/1591669)).